# How to Reshape Numpy from (876,) to (876,256,256,3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have numpy array that contains 876 images. Each image being of size 256x256x3. When I print shape of array I get (876,) where as I want to reshape it to (876,256,256,3).

When I try to use arrary.reshape(-1,256,256,3) I run into errors saying cannot reshape array of (876,) to (876,256,256,3).

Here is the code snippet:

```
for x in trainList:
    #print(x[0])
    #samples = []
    #samples.append(x[0])
    name = glob.glob("./"+str(TrainFolder)+"/"+x[0])
    img = img_to_array(load_img(name[0], color_mode='rgb', target_size=[im_width,im_height]))
    #samples.append(img)
    #samples.append(x[1])
    temp = [x[0],img,x[1]]    
    trainSet.append(temp)
testList[:] = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0] for x in testList]    
for x in testList:
    #print(x)
    #samples = []
    #samples.append(x)
    #img = cv2.imread("./TestImages/"+x+".jpg")
    #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    name = glob.glob("./TestImages/"+x+"*")
    img = img_to_array(load_img(name[0], color_mode='rgb', target_size=[im_width,im_height]))
    #samples.append(img) 
    temp = [x,img]    
    testSet.append(temp)
print("Train Data Shape "+str(len(trainSet))) 
print("Test Data Shape "+str(len(testSet)))  

trainSet = np.asarray(trainSet) 
testSet = np.asarray(testSet)
print("Train Data Shape "+str(trainSet.shape))
print("Test Data Shape "+str(testSet.shape))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(trainSet[:,1], trainSet[:,2], test_size=0.33)
print(X_train.shape,y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape,y_test.shape)
```

Please advise a solution.

Comment: What format are your images in? could you post the code that loads the images and creates this array?

Comment: Added the code. Please look at the question now.

Comment: Could you also post the definitions of `img_to_array` and `load_img` please?

Comment: They are keras function that load images and convert to array.

Comment: `reshape` can't change the total number of elements.  I suspect your `(876,)` shape array is object dtype (check that), containing arrays.  But one or more of the arrays is not the expet (256,256,3) shape, and as a result `np.asarray` can't make the expected 4d array.  You could try `np.stack(your_array)`.  If it gives an error, that will confirm my hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

You create `trainSet` by appending (to a list);

```
temp = [x[0],img,x[1]]    
trainSet.append(temp)
```

Looks like `x` is some sort of string or strings, used to construct filenames.  `img` is array created from loading an image.  So `temp` is a list, a mix of strings and array.

```
trainSet = np.asarray(trainSet)
```

Given that input list, this array will necessarily be a 1d object dtype array.  It can't make a multidimensional array from that list.

`testSet` is a different list, but still a mix of strings and arrays:

```
temp = [x,img]    
testSet.append(temp)
```

Let's try to recreate that

```
In [708]: alist = []                                                                                   
In [709]: alist.append(['x0', np.ones((2,3),int), 'x1'])                                               
In [710]: alist.append(['x0', np.ones((2,3),int), 'x1'])                                               
In [711]: alist                                                                                        
Out[711]: 
[['x0', array([[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]]), 'x1'], ['x0', array([[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]]), 'x1']]
In [712]: np.array(alist)                                                                              
Out[712]: 
array([['x0', array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]), 'x1'],
       ['x0', array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]), 'x1']], dtype=object)
In [713]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[713]: (2, 3)
```

OK, I was expecting a (2,) shape, instead got (2,3).  So my reading of your code must be off.

I could extract the array part with indexing and `stack`:

```
In [718]: np.stack(_712[:,1])                                                                          
Out[718]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]])
In [719]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[719]: (2, 2, 3)
```

In any case, we can't help without more information about the list(s) that go into the `np.array(...)` calls.  Or at least some info on the array that your trying to reshape.